# Clearing up doubts on rules of differentiation

Tags: calculus

As I just started learning the different rules of differentiation, I have some burning question marks in my head as such in the picture . I'm required to differentiate the following with respect to $x$.

> **1)**
>   $$\frac{2x^2+4x}{x}$$
>   **2)**
>   $$\frac{(1-x)(x-2)}{x}$$

For 1. It is easy to bring the $x$ up and then differentiate from there .

For 2. Once I bring the $x$ up , I'm stuck as I can't differentiate it from 
$x^{-1}((1-x)(x-2))$ 
I was told not to change the question by expanding $(1-x)(x-2)$ ..
So is there any way that I can use the rule of addition and subtraction of function to solve this ?

Comment: @projectilemotion yes ! This can only be solved by product and quotient rule ?

Comment: That is not the only method, but it is one way to evaluate it's derivative.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you mean by "I was told not to change the question".

This is to answer question **2)**. I assumed that you know how to do **1)**. Please correct me if I am wrong.

---

Since you cannot expand the $(1-x)(x-2)$, start by applying the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) on the numerator:
$$(uv)'=u'v+uv'$$
Therefore, we have:
$$\begin{matrix} u=1-x & v=x-2 \\ u'=-1 & v'=1 \end{matrix}$$
Hence, the derivative of what is on the numerator is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}((1-x)(x-2))=2-x+1-x=3-2x \tag{1}$$

---

We can now apply the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule):
$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$
Letting:
$$\begin{matrix} f=(1-x)(x-2) & g=x \\ f'=3-2x & g'=1\end{matrix}$$
Note that we obtained $f'$ from equation $(1)$.

Applying the quotient rule should give you the result you require after simplification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only allowed to use sum rule, there is no real way getting around expanding the binomial. Note that
$$
f(x)
\colon=\frac{(1-x)(x-2)}{x}
=\left(1-x\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)
=3-\frac{2}{x}-x.
$$
So
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}-1.
$$